# trying to convert/map the Objects in my JSON array to my KO observable function

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, knockout.js

I have an JSON array that I read in, now I want to make each object in the array a KO observable so that it can be mapped to the function

```
function Person(data)
{
    this.name = ko.observable(data.name);
    this.age = ko.observable(data.age);
    this.link = ko.observable(data.link);  
}

function ViewModel()
{
    var self = this;    
    self.Persons = ko.observableArray([]);

    var JSONdataFromServer;
    $.getJSON('http://127.0.0.1:8080', function(data) {
        self.Persons(data);
        for(var k in self.Persons) {
            k = $.map(k, function(item) { return new Person(item) });
        }
    });
}
```

However When I run this code(this is only a portion of it) I get the error "Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '0' in G". Again all I want to do is convert the JSON object in the Persons array to a Person KO observable object.

Answer (score 0):

`self.Persons` is an observableArray, so if you want to look at its contents, you need to invoke it:

```
for (var k in self.Persons())
```

Other things you're doing are perplexing me. To convert the JSON object to an observableArray of `Person`s, you'd likely do something like this (depending on what the data looks like -- you don't say):

```
$.getJSON('http://127.0.0.1:8080', function(data) {
    var arrayOfPersons = ko.utils.arrayMap(data, function (item) {
        return new Person(item);
    });
    self.Persons(arrayOfPersons);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid manually mapping incoming data from the server. Use [ko mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) for this. Maintaining your client side viewModel in sync with data from the server is very hard as soon as your viewModel starts growing, better to leverage this to ko mapping, which is also very flexible if you need more control over how the mapping should work.